# Run a script that uses my models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have the following need.

I have a Rails web application. I need to write a script that will read the excel file, and call methods of my model to fill the database.

This is not a problem.

I am just wondering:

Is there something a bit like seed.rb where I can just run the .rb file and it will just make the changes?

like: `rails runmyfile myfile.rb`

That file will read the spreadsheet and input the data. I would use seed.rb, but that will not let me add things while the server is running.

Comment: How often do you need to do this? It might be worth setting up a job if you're pulling the Excel files from somewhere. Otherwise rake probably works fine for something like this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try creating a `rake` task for it. Then just

```
rake my_tasks:task_name
```

More info on custom `rake` tasks can be found [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/command_line.html#custom-rake-tasks)

Answer (score 1):

Yes [rails runner](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/command_line.html#rails-runner) is what you are looking for.

```
$ bin/rails runner  -e staging myfile.rb
```

Read the usuage from your console :

```
$ bin/rails runner
Usage: rails runner [options] [<'Some.ruby(code)'> | <filename.rb>]

    -e, --environment=name           Specifies the environment for the runner to operate under (test/development/production).
                                     Default: development

    -h, --help                       Show this help message.

Examples:
    rails runner 'puts Rails.env'
        This runs the code `puts Rails.env` after loading the app

    rails runner path/to/filename.rb
        This runs the Ruby file located at `path/to/filename.rb` after loading the app

You can also use runner as a shebang line for your executables:
    -------------------------------------------------------------
    #!/usr/bin/env /Users/xxx/rails/app/bin/rails runner

    Product.all.each { |p| p.price *= 2 ; p.save! }
    -------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for [rails runner](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/command_line.html#rails-runner), which runs any Ruby script in your rails environment, giving you access to your models, etc.

```
$ echo 'puts "hi"' > test.rb
$ rails runner test.rb
hi
```

Or run a small snippet directly from the command line.

```
$ rails runner 'puts "hi"'
hi
```

Answer (score 0):

I use rails [runner](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/command_line.html#rails-runner) for this purpose. The *runner* runs a snippet of code directly, but with a full fledged rails environment. If you want to run a script (assuming your script is under "lib/myscript.rb"), in a rails-environment, then run:

```
rails runner lib/myscript.rb
```

If you want to run the script in a specific environment, then use the `-e` parameter:

```
rails runner -e development lib/myscript.rb
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this with the CSV library and incorporate it into a rake task:

```
desc "add models from csv file"
task :add_csv_models => :environment do
  require 'csv'
  CSV.foreach('path/to/your_file.csv') do |row|
    mod = YourModel.new(attribute_1: row[0], attribute_2: row[1])
      if mod.save
        printf "\nModel Saved"
      else
        # handle exception here
      end
  end
end
```

Then run rake:add_csv_models
You'll have to tweak the attributes and row indexes, but this should give you the general idea.